# Why are acyclic fibrations called so?

Tags: category-theory, soft-question, model-categories

This question refers to [acyclic fibrations](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/acyclic+fibration) in model categories.
Why is the word "acyclic" being used here? Is there a reason for it, at least in a particular case such as algebraic topology or simplicial sets?
The same question can be made for acyclic cofibrations.
I searched thouroughly but found no mention whatsoever to why they have this name.

edit: in *Homotopical Algebra*, Quillen calls acyclic fibrations by trivial fibrations instead. Could anybody tell where was the first term coined?

Comment: For a topological space to be acyclic means that its reduced homology groups are all trivial. From there the word gets generalized. For example,  I believe I have heard the term acyclic applied to a continuous function $f : X \to Y$, with some meaning like $f$ inducing isomorphisms in reduced homology, or perhaps some more explicit condition on the induced map of chain complexes $f_\# : C_*(X) \to C_*(Y)$. And from there, no doubt, the word gets generalized even further.

Comment: An acyclic cofibration is precisely a cofibration that is bijective in $\pi_0$ and $\pi_1$ and has all relative homology groups trivial. If the spaces are known to have abelian $\pi_1$ in advance then the condition on relative homology is enough.